# formGroup expects a FormGroup instance: smart and dumb component

Tags: angular, angular2-formbuilder, angular-forms

I have a reactive form that is pushed from a smart component to a dumb component, and I know that this error means the form is not being bound for some reason, I just can't figure out why...

I have looked at it with augery, and cannot find the issue. I have reloaded my code, and re-served it with no luck. I based this exactly off a working version I already have, and cannot seem to find any differences. I went through all the steps, I created the var, created the formGroup onInit, added the form control, passed it to the child component, used @Input, and created the form binding and formControl name in the html.

Is it because it's rendering before the form can be bound? how do I fix this?

the full error is:

```
ERROR Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.
```

pointing to the first line of my form in my dumb component.
and

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
```

when I try to read the form state in the html

view.ts

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Dns } from './../models/network.models';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { NetworkValidator } from './../networkValidator.service';
import { NetworkService } from './../network.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dns-view',
  templateUrl: './dns-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dns-view.component.css']
})
export class DnsViewComponent implements OnInit {

    dnsForm: FormGroup;
    dnsServers$: Observable<string[]>;

    constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
                private networkService: NetworkService,
                private networkValidator: NetworkValidator) {}

    ngOnInit() {

        this.dnsForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            ip: [null, Validators.required, this.networkValidator.validateNetwork('ip')]
        });

    }
```

view.html

```
<app-dns
    [dnsServers$]="dnsServers$"
    [dnsForm]="dnsForm"
    (addIp)="addIp($event)"
    (deleteIp)="deleteIp($event)"
>
</app-dns>
```

dumb.ts

```
import { Dns } from './../models/network.models';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-dns',
    templateUrl: './dns.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./dns.component.css']
})
export class DnsComponent {
    // initialize form vars
    @Input() dnsServers$;
    @Input() dnsForm: FormGroup;
    // @Input() editForm: FormGroup;

    @Output() deleteIp: EventEmitter<Dns> = new EventEmitter<Dns>();
    @Output() addIp: EventEmitter<FormGroup> = new EventEmitter<FormGroup>();


}
```

dumb.html

```
<div class="title row">
    <div class="col">
        DNS
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col"></div>
        <div class="server-list col-7">
            <div
                class="server row"
                *ngFor="let server of dnsServers$ | async; let index = index"
            >
                <div class="read row"
                    appListHighlight
                    [index]="index"
                >
                    <div class="col"></div>
                    <div class="col-3">
                        <label for="servers">
                            {{ server }}
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col"></div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="x">
                            <i
                                class="fa fa-times-circle"
                                aria-hidden="true"
                                (click)="deleteIp.emit(server)"
                            ></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col"></div>
    </div>
    <form
        autocomplete="off"
        [formGroup]="dnsForm"
        (ngSubmit)="addIp.emit(dnsForm)"
    >
        <div class="add-server row">
            <div class="col"></div>
            <div class="col-2">
                <label for="add-server">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
                        Add Server IP
                    </button>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-5">
                <input
                    type="text"
                    class="form-control"
                    formControlName="ip"
                    placeholder="8.8.8.8"
                >
                <div
                    class="invalid-box alert alert-danger"
                    *ngIf="!dnsForm.get('ip').valid && dnsForm.get('ip').dirty"
                >
                    Invalid IP address
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col"></div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the exact error message ? Also did you try the `ngAfterViewInit()` hook ?

Comment: I would bet on an error in form creation causing the error you are stating.
Does `this.networkValidator.validateNetwork('ip')` returns a function ? If no here is your problem.

Comment: hey @GrégoryElhaimer, yes it does return a function and is already working on other components.

Comment: @AlexBeugnet the full error is: "ERROR Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in."

Comment: @AlexBeugnet would I put my formbuilder code inside that hook in my view component? or in my dumb component? I dont really understand this, since I have a component set up in the exact same way, without using ngAfterViewInit(), and it works great

Comment: could be that in the first pass before you initialize your form you are inputting the value of your form in the dumb component and getting this error. check on ngOnChanges() hook in your dumb component if you get any value for your form

Comment: FormBuilder group method is waiting an array of function for validators. Try removing the validator and check if it works.

Comment: @GrégoryElhaimer alright, i removed it, still nothing

Comment: @JayDeeEss nothing is showing

Answer (score 1):

I think it is due to not having a valid `formGroup` object present to be passed to your dumb component as an input property while the smart component is 'construct'ed. Try to instantiate the `formGroup` instance within the `constructor` of your smart component (currently you are doing it inside the `OnInit` hook).

> view.ts

```
export class DnsViewComponent {

 dnsForm: FormGroup;
 dnsServers$: Observable<string[]>;

 constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
            private networkService: NetworkService,
            private networkValidator: NetworkValidator) {
  this.dnsForm = formBuilder.group({
        ip: [null, [Validators.required, networkValidator.validateNetwork('ip')]]
    }); // 'networkValidator' referenced without 'this.' as it is a constructor argument
 }
// no ngOnInit hook implementation
}
```

See if that fixes your issue.

Comment: Was thinking the same, there should be no other reason for that not to work

Comment: @amal I tried this, still not working, same error :/

Comment: I have updated my answer. See if changing this helps: `ip: [null, [Validators.required, networkValidator.validateNetwork('ip')]]` extra `[]` around the Validators list

Comment: @amal that just puts a sync and async validator in the sync part of the validators array, that doesn't work

Comment: sorry, didn't realize your second validator was an 'async' one

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I was rendering my dumb component in my router, not my smart component.

silly mistake, took me hours. thanks for all the help guys.